# PDO MysQL "Update" statement not saving to DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Very new to programming myself so excuse silly mistakes .. i have a PDF MySQL statement that refuses to work. I can successfully pass it data via Ajax / POST but it will not apply to the DB.

1. I have prepared a "Database" class based on the following guidance [PDO Class](http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/) and have extended that to an "Email" class with the following function included:

   ```php
   public function updateEmailTemplate($emailTemplateDescription, 
                   $emailTemplateSubject, $emailTemplateBody,
                   $emailTemplateType, $id)
   {
       $this->query('UPDATE email_templates 
                        SET emailTemplateTitle = :title,
                            emailTemplateSubject = :subject,
                            emailTemplateBody = :body, 
                            emailTemplateType = :type 
                      WHERE emailTemplateID= :id');        
       $this->bind(':title', $emailTemplateDescription);
       $this->bind(':subject', $emailTemplateSubject);
       $this->bind(':body', $emailTemplateBody);
       $this->bind(':type', $emailTemplateType);
       $this->bind(':id', $id);
       $this->execute();

       if ($this->lastInsertId() == true) {
           echo 'Template added successfully';
       } else {
           echo 'There was an error';
       }
   }
   ```

   2. I can verify that it does receive the variable parameters by "Echoing" the data when the function runs.

When it runs though i simply get "There was an Error" and nothing has been updated in the DB ... Any ideas?

3. As requested I've added the based Database class code as well

```js
class Database{
    private $host      = "localhost";
    private $user      = "root";
    private $pass      = "MyP@ymentPortal";
    private $dbname    = "mppcompany";
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
 private $stmt;
 
    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
 
 
 public function query($query){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}
 

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}


public function execute(){
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}


public function resultset(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}


public function single(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}


public function rowCount(){
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}


public function lastInsertId(){
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}


 
public function beginTransaction(){
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}


public function endTransaction(){
    return $this->dbh->commit();
}


public function cancelTransaction(){
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}


public function debugDumpParams(){
    return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
}


}
```

4. And here is the full extended class code

```js
class email extends Database {


public function emailTemplates() {

       $this->query('SELECT * FROM email_templates');
        $rows = $this->resultset();
  return $rows;
    }
 
 
public function selectOneEmail($id) {

       $this->query('SELECT * FROM email_templates WHERE emailTemplateID=:id');
        $this->bind(':id', $id);
  $this->execute();
  $row = $this->single();
     return $row;
 }





 public function createEmailTemplate($emailTemplateDescription, $emailTemplateSubject, $emailTemplateBody) {

        $this-> query('INSERT INTO email_templates (emailTemplateTitle, emailTemplateSubject, emailTemplateBody, emailTemplateType) VALUES (:title, :subject, :body, 1)');

        $this-> bind(':title', $emailTemplateDescription);
        $this-> bind(':subject', $emailTemplateSubject);
        $this-> bind(':body', $emailTemplateBody);

        $this-> execute();

        if ($this-> lastInsertId() == true) {
            echo 'Template added successfully';
        } else {
            echo 'There was an error';
        }


    }
 
 
 
 
  public function updateEmailTemplate($emailTemplateDescription, $emailTemplateSubject, $emailTemplateBody, $emailTemplateType, $id) {

$this->query('UPDATE email_templates SET emailTemplateTitle = :title, emailTemplateSubject = :subject, emailTemplateBody = :body, emailTemplateType = :type WHERE emailTemplateID= :id');
    
        $this-> bind(':title', $emailTemplateDescription);
        $this-> bind(':subject', $emailTemplateSubject);
        $this-> bind(':body', $emailTemplateBody);
   $this->bind(':type', $emailTemplateType);
  $this-> bind(':id', $id);
        $this-> execute();
  


    }
 
 

 public function deleteEmailTemplate($id)
{
$this->query('DELETE FROM email_templates WHERE emailTemplateID=:id');
$this->bind(':id', $id);
$this->execute();

if ($this->execute() > 0)
{echo 'Template Deleted';
}else{
echo 'Error Deleting Template';
}}

 
 
 
 
 
 
 
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the output line must be the other one?

Comment: You are doing an `UPDATE` query, which does not affect `lastInsertId()`.  Do you have PDO configured for `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` as suggested in that tutorial? If any error occurs, it should throw an exception.  You cannot check `lastInsertId()` for an `UPDATE` and get a meaningful result though.

Comment: I would sort of recommend against using this PDO wrapper class, mainly because it renames methods with thin wrappers like `bindParam() -> bind()` and creates a `query()` method which apparently does a `prepare()`, while PDO _already_ has a `query()` method for raw querying.  PDO already has a pretty easy to use API, so this seems like overkill and extra complication.

Comment: Thanks for the comments i will take this into consideration as we move further forward

Comment: Also yes i do have "PDF::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION" configured in the base class

Comment: Thanks all jsxqf,  i've now got all code from the base DB class and the extended Email class attached

Comment: Cheers i have made this public now but hasn't made a difference yet... to confirm a few more details ...  1. The other methods in the class "create, delete, read" all do work , its just Update that seems to fail   2.  Im now getting a Post response of : " Reload the page to get source for: /controllers/emailController.php , if that helps?

Comment: Apologies about the delay!  I've echo'd each of the variables after 'execute' and they def do display

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is `lastInsertId()` - as the name suggests, it returns the auto_increment from the last **insert** - but you don't do any insert.

So you need to check for success with a different method, maybe just using exceptions would suffice.

Comment: Thanks i have removed the success query, but the method still doesn't appear to apply any DB data ... nor does it throw an exception up

Comment: Any further suggestions , both on what coudl be causing this ... also Eugen have u got a suggestion on the best success method to use in this case?